# Burnside's formula on a octagon

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZAlH.png)

I'm thinking that maybe I have to use burnsides lemma to determine how many possible outcomes there are, but someone said there are only one in a) and in b) there are two.
Can someone explain how that is possible, or if I should use burnsides lemma, and how I could do that?

Comment: These things are called "necklaces" and "bracelets", and counting them is a well known problem. You can look them up. Yes, you use Burnside lemma. The answers you quote are wrong.

Comment: So, i have drawn them and found 36 different, is that correct? But how can I write is as a calculation?

Comment: Yes, 36 is correct. You can check here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html

Comment: More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)